# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un string con otros string dentro de un for y agregar un "OR" en el medio? C#

Tags: c#, string, loops

He intentado diferentes formas de guardar cadenas pero no sé cómo puedo guardarlas con un *OR* en el medio para hacer una consulta usando `bs.Filter`.

`dptA[i]` es una lista

`or` es un *string* que contiene = " OR ";

```
for (int i = 0; i < dptA.Count; i++) {

    filtro = "(UdResponsable LIKE '" + dptA[i] + "')";
    filtroAux = filtro;

    filtro = filtroAux +or+filtro;

    Console.WriteLine(filtro);
}
```

El resultado final tiene que ser ***(UdResponsable LIKE 'PRSDRTF') OR (UdResponsable LIKE 'ASDFADSF')***

Comment: El lenguaje oficial del sitio es el **Español**, por favor traduce tu pregunta antes de que sea candidata de cierre.

Comment: gracias @frikinside pensaba que se podía preguntar en ingles también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se podría resolver de diferentes formas. 
Inicializando la variable fuera del `for` e ir concatenando cada nuevo filtro junto con un or pero te deja con la "fea" necesidad de controlar el primer o último elemento para evitar tener un `OR` sobrante.

Me decantaría más por hacer uso de [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IList<string> lista_filtros = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dptA.Count; i++) {
    lista_filtros.Add("(UdResponsable LIKE '" + dptA[i] + "')");
}
var filtro_completo = String.Join(" OR ",lista_filtros);
```

---

Si quisiéramos utilizar concatenaciones en lugar de hacer uso de `String.Join` podríamos hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
string filtro = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < dptA.Count; i++) {
    if (i > 0) { //Sólo queremos que nos añada el 'OR' si no es el primer elemento
        filtro += or;
    }
    filtro += "(UdResponsable LIKE '" + dptA[i] + "')";
}
```

---

Siguiendo la línea de la concatenación, también podríamos usar [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2839d5h5(v=vs.110).aspx) para ir construyendo el `string` en lugar de utilizar una concatenación "*manual*":

```
StringBuilder filtro_sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < dptA.Count; i++) {
    if (i > 0) { //Sólo queremos que nos añada el 'OR' si no es el primer elemento
        filtro_sb.Append(or);
    }
    filtro_sb.Append("(UdResponsable LIKE '" + dptA[i] + "')");
}
var filtro_completo = filtro_sb.ToString();
```

---

En relación a la [respuesta de Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115942/38581), podríamos evitarnos totalmente el `String.Join` usando el método de extensión de `LINQ` [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dptA = new List<string> {"PRSDRTF", "ASDFADSF"};
var filtr_cmmpleto = dptA.Select(x => $"(UdResponsable LIKE '{x}')").Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a} OR {b}");
```

Comment: @CBrionesM yo veo bien esta respuesta. Si no es exactamente lo que quieres, edita tu pregunta y aclara exactamente cual es tu duda.

Comment: @CBrionesM la variable `filtro_completo` obtendría el resultado deseado. O eso me pareció según la pregunta, podrías aclarar el problema editando la pregunta?

Comment: @frikinside voy a probar si no funciona como deseo replanteo la pregunta, lo siento por las molestias

Comment: @frikinside gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente y estoy probando tambien con los otros ejemplos, +1.

Comment: @CBrionesM Me alegro de que te sirviera. Por favor, indícame si necesitas alguna aclaración para cualquiera de los modos.

Comment: @frikinside todo claro, ya he caído en como hacerlo, hay veces que me estanco y no se como salir.

Comment: @CBrionesM nada, en ocasiones pasa. No obstante, estoy seguro que la opción de concatenar se te habría pasado por la cabeza de una forma u otra antes o después

Answer (score 1):

Una versión más compacta utilizando `string.Join` y LINQ, en la línea de lo que propone @frikinside:

```
    var dptA = new List<string> {"PRSDRTF", "ASDFADSF"};
    var filtroCommpleto = string.Join(" OR ", dptA.Select(x => $"(UdResponsable LIKE '{x}')"));
```

Comment: +1 Me gusta! Tanto por el uso de `LINQ` como por la sintaxis de [cadenas interpoladas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). Viendo tu respuesta, se me ocurrió también la posibilidad de olvidarnos de `String.Join` completamente y usar `Aggregate` en su lugar para tener una respuesta puramente `LINQ`